# How to read a .txt document line by line in android?

Tags: android, readline

In this code, only the last word entered in the .txt file is being read. I am calling the same activity when a condition is met. What changes should I make to the code so that it reads a word, calls the same activity again and then reads a new word?

```
public class Page extends Activity {

    Button b;
    TextView t;
    EditText e;
    int i = 0;
    String str2;
    String w, x=null;

    static BufferedReader c = null;
    static BufferedReader ic = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.benter);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        InputStream f = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.incorrect);
        ic = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));

        try {
            while ((w = ic.readLine()) != null) {
                    t.setText(w);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            str2 = e.getText().toString();

                            if (str2.equals(x)) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                Intent open = new Intent(Page.this, Page.class);
                                startActivity(open);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                e.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is minot mistake in your onClickListener() :

```
public class Page extends Activity {

Button b;
TextView t;
EditText e;
int i = 0;
String str2;
String w, x=null;

static BufferedReader c = null;
static BufferedReader ic = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.benter);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    InputStream f = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.incorrect);
    ic = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));

    try {
        while ((w = ic.readLine()) != null) {
                t.setText(w);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        str2 = e.getText().toString();
                        // it was str2.equals(x) nut x is null, replace w with x
                        if (str2.equals(w)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            Intent open = new Intent(Page.this, Page.class);
                            startActivity(open);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This code will work for you

Answer (score 2):

You can read file line by line using this code

```
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("FilePath");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String data = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(data);
        }

        System.out.println(builder.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your code there is problem in your onclick listener .. please put onclick listener on out of while loop..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons I/O library for this.It's so simple. And keep your code beauty. And why do get .txt files from assets ?

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream fs = am.open("a.txt");
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(file,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your text file in "Assets" folder of project and use following code to retrieve that file in java class

```
 try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("YOUR_TEXT_FILE.txt")));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    message=total.toString();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After that you have that file in String message

Answer (score 0):

Your program is reading the last line because you are overwriting your 'w' variable every time that you are calling the readLine() method. What you should do is set your 'w' variable empty, and ***append*** it with readLine() to keep all the lines in your text file that have been read, then call setText() once to place everything in your View. Without appending, you are essentially overwriting the 'w' variable every time your while loop runs through, which is why you are receiving the last line from your text file.